# Compare with two dataframes and replace the columns values of two columns using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have two dataframes df1 and df2, which look like this;

df1:

> ```
>     Task Name        |  Task Role
> ------------------------------
> Review done-RE432        Assignee1
> Result generated         Manager1
> Results-RW212312         Assignee2
> #hold-results            Assignee2
> Change received-WE22321  Assignee2 
> ...
> ```

df2:

> ```
> Task Names
> ----------
> Review change
> Results generated
> Review done
> Change received
> ...
> ```

Now, I have to create another column in df1 named as 'Task Name Support' with column values based on conditions:

1. if the task name from df1 matches/has a part of it (such as. Review done from df2 matched with Review done-RE432)  then write the value(Review Done) from df2 into "Task Name Support"
2. Else, (if '#hold-results') write the same value(#hold-results) from df1
3. And if there is match, then do nothing to Task Role.
4. If there is no match then, replace the 'Task Role' to 'Unknown'.

I want the results like this:

df1:

> ```
> Task Name             |    Task Role       |    Task Name Suppport
> Review done-RE432          Assignee1           Review done
> Result generated           Manager1            Results generated
> Results-RW212312           Unknown             Results-RW212312
> #hold-results              Unknown             #hold-results
> Change received-WE22321    Assignee2           Change received
> ...
> ```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves your question:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'TaskName': ['Review done-RE432', 'Result generated', 'Results-RW212312', '#hold-results', 'Change received-WE22321'], 
                    'TaskRole': ['Assignee1', 'Manager1', 'Assignee2', 'Assignee2', 'Assignee2']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'TaskName': ['Review change','Result generated','Review done', 'Change received']})

df1['tmp_name'] = df1['TaskName'].str.split('-').str[0]
df1.loc[df1['tmp_name'] == '#hold', 'tmp_name'] = '#hold-results'
result = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left', left_on='tmp_name', right_on='TaskName', suffixes=['', ' Support'])
result.loc[result['TaskName Support'].isna(), 'TaskRole'] = 'Unknown'
result['TaskName Support'].fillna(result.TaskName,inplace=True)

result.drop(columns='tmp_name')
```

Returns:

```
                  TaskName   TaskRole  TaskName Support
0        Review done-RE432  Assignee1       Review done
1         Result generated   Manager1  Result generated
2         Results-RW212312    Unknown  Results-RW212312
3            #hold-results    Unknown     #hold-results
4  Change received-WE22321  Assignee2   Change received
```

Comment: I mean its not just the case #hold. If there's no match then I shouldn't really do anything, I just need to keep the same Task Name from df1.

Comment: Please explain to me what differs in my answer from your expected output?

Comment: Thanks, Its working fine, I made a few tweaks to it

Comment: In that case could you please share those tweeks and accept my answer? Thank you!